# Place a static variable which returned as a respond within a recursive block

Tags: python

I wrote such a recursive solution to merge two sorted list

```
res = []
def merge(l1, l2):
    """
    :type l1:List
    :rtype res: List[int]
    """
    #Base
    #Case1: Both are empty Case2 and Case3: One of them is empty
    if len(l1) * len(l2) == 0:
        res = l1 + l2 
        return res
    #Case 4    
    if len(l1) = 1 and len(l2) = 1:
        if l1[0] <= l2[0]:
            res.append(l1.pop(0)) #decrement 
        else:
            res.append(l2.pop(0))
        return res

    #Recur Case
    if len(l1) > 1 and len(l2) > 1:
        return merge(l1, l2)
```

The problem I concern is that the static variable `res` should be defined outside of the function module. In this case,  I might forget to copy `res=[]` when reuse it in other place. module `merge` is not independent in a 100% way.

So I place it inside like

```
def merge(l1, l2):
    """
    :type l1:List
    :rtype res: List[int]
    """
    global res
    try:
        print(res)
    except NameError:
        res = []
...
```

The solution is cumbersome,
How could solve the problem in a succinct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could throw in `res` as a parameter into the function. Since it's mutable it should also get passed by reference and won't take up any more memory (other than the recursion itself).

Or you could wrap it in a class and access it with `self.res`, however that would serve the same logic as passing on the variable in the recursion as below.

```
def merge(l1, l2, res=None):
    """
    :type l1:List
    :rtype res: List[int]
    """
    # Default parameter, read more here on why not to initialise as list
    # https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments
    if res is None:
        res = []
    #Base
    #Case1: Both are empty Case2 and Case3: One of them is empty
    if len(l1) * len(l2) == 0:
        res = l1 + l2 
        return res
    #Case 4    
    if len(l1) = 1 and len(l2) = 1:
        if l1[0] <= l2[0]:
            res.append(l1.pop(0)) #decrement 
        else:
            res.append(l2.pop(0))
        return res

    #Recur Case
    if len(l1) > 1 and len(l2) > 1:
        return merge(l1, l2, res)
```

Comment: I think the function definition should be `def merge(l1, l2, res=[]):`, as res should always be initiated as `[]`

Comment: no, res = [] will shadow in recursive cases @Recessive

Comment: @Recessive I forgot that part, but added the *functionality* now. However, default mutable arguments doesn't really behave as you'd like to. You can [read more here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) on why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot about that. You're right, I've made that mistake before when writing recursive functions.